# Implementaion of Mini Batch K-Means

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

Planing to implement Mini Batch K-Means on a large scale dataset resembles to [sklean.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mini-batch-kmeans).

> In the first step, b samples are drawn randomly from the dataset, to
> form a mini-batch. These are then assigned to the nearest centroid. In
> the second step, the centroids are updated. In contrast to k-means,
> this is done on a per-sample basis. For each sample in the mini-batch,
> the assigned centroid is updated by taking the streaming average of
> the sample and all previous samples assigned to that centroid.

**sklean description (I might misunderstood the sklearn doc):**

In terms of first step, it says that only assign newly sampled data to their closest clusters. What about the samples drew from previous rounds, shouldn't we also update them.

**My understanding:**

In the first step, assign these newly drawn data along with all previous samples if any to the nearest centroid.

Which would be a common implementaion for mini batch K-Means? Suppose, we do not update previous samples to their nearest clusters, will the K-Means converge?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you suggest assigning *all data points* to their nearest centroids, then update all centroids to be the mean of the points assigned to them. This is Lloyd's algorithm, which is the typical *batch* algorithm used to solved k-means. It would no longer operate on *mini-batches*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not all, but assigning current batch and reassigning data from past batches since centroids get updated.